# Клонирование git-репозитория подподпроекта в каталог сборки из каталога с исходниками в cmake-проекте

Tags: git, cmake

В своей работе я использую сторонний cmake-проект, который имеет подпроекты в виде `git submodules`. Данные подпроекты также имеют свои подподпроекты в виде `git submodules`.
Cmake-проект, его подпроекты и подподпроекты представляют собой git-репозитории, хранящиеся на внешнем git-хранилище.

При клонировании cmake-проекта с рекурсивной загрузкой подпроектов (`git submodule update --init --recursive`) все подпроекты и подподпроекты корректно выкачиваются в подкаталоги каталога с исходными файлами, как мной и ожидается.

Мне необходимо переделать проект таким образом, чтобы его можно было собрать локально без доступа к внешнему git-хранилищу, используя ранее выкаченные подпроекты и подподпроекты в каталоге с исходными файлами.

Cmake-проект при сборке копирует все подпроекты из каталога с исходными файлами в каталог сборки и собирает их там из исходников. Это делается с помощью cmake-функции `ExternalProject_Add`, у которой в качестве параметра `GIT_REPOSITORY` задаётся путь к подкаталогу каталога с исходными файлами для подпроекта.

Однако, функция `ExternalProject_Add` клонирует из каталога сборки подпроекты, НО НЕ КЛОНИРУЕТ ОТТУДА ПОДПОДПРОЕКТЫ – это я вижу в логе сборки, который выводится в консоль – после регистрации подподмодуля выполняется обращение к репозиторию этого подподмодуля на внешнем git-хранилище.

Насколько я могу судить, функция `ExternalProject_Add` берёт расположение подподпроектов из `.gitmodules` подпроекта, где как раз записаны ссылки на внешнее git-хранилище. ***Эти ссылки я не планирую менять, чтобы не сломалась рекурсивная загрузка подпроектов в каталог исходников***.

В подпроекте, который имеет подподпроекты, не используется функция `ExternalProject_Add`. Зависимости подпроекта, как я вижу, задаются только в `.gitmodules`.

Таким образом, для корректной сборки проекта, необходимо, чтобы при сборке, когда у проекта нет доступа к внешнему git-хранилищу, в каталог сборки клонировались и исходники подпроекта, и исходники подподпроекта.

В связи с этим, вопрос: ***как лучше (т. е. с минимальными правками проекта) средствами `cmake` и/или `git` организовать копирование подподпроектов из каталога исходников в каталог сборки при выполнении сборки проекта***?

Answer (score 0):

Решено.

В функции `ExternalProject_Add`, с помощью которого в проект подключался подпроект, вместо параметров `GIT_*` стал использовать параметр `URL`, указывая ему каталог подпроекта в каталоге исходников. До этого у меня не было опыта в `ExternalProject_Add`, поэтому я не знал, что так можно делать. Теперь подпроект копируется вместе с подподпроектами из каталога с исходниками в каталог сборки.

Подпроект уже находится в нужном коммите (это было сделано путём указания нужной ветки при добавлении этого подпроекта как `git submodules`), поэтому указание `GIT_TAG` мне здесь не нужно.